# Making a new column by subtracting values based on a key in R?

Tags: r

I have a data table like this

```
ID      DAYS    FREQUENCY
"ads"   20      3
"jwa"   45      2
"mno"   4       1
"ads"   13      3
"jwa"   60      2
"ads"   18      3
```

I want to add a column that subtracts the days based on the id and subtract the closest days together.
My new table would like like this:

```
ID      DAYS    FREQUENCY    DAYS DIFF
"ads"   20      3            2 (because 20-18) 
"jwa"   45      2            NA (because no value greater than 45 for that id)
"mno"   4       1            NA
"ads"   13      3            NA
"jwa"   60      2            15
"ads"   18      3            5
```

Bonus: Is there a way to use the merge function?

Comment: Why would you want / expect to use a merge here? Fwiw, if you're willing to install a package, this can be done with `library(data.table); setDT(DF)[order(DAYS), dd := DAYS - shift(DAYS), by=ID]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(row.order = row_number()) %>% # row numbers added to preserve original row order
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(DAYS) %>%
  mutate(lag = lag(DAYS)) %>%
  mutate(days.diff = DAYS - lag) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(row.order) %>%
  select(ID, DAYS, FREQUENCY, days.diff)
```

Output:

```
      ID  DAYS FREQUENCY days.diff
  <fctr> <int>     <int>     <int>
1    ads    20         3         2
2    jwa    45         2        NA
3    mno     4         1        NA
4    ads    13         3        NA
5    jwa    60         2        15
6    ads    18         3         5
```

Comment: You don't need to make two mutate calls in a row. `mutate(x = g(z), y = f(x))` is a doable thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using dplyr and a quick loop:

```
library(dplyr)

# Rowwise data.frame creation because I'm too lazy not to copy-paste the example data
df <- tibble::frame_data(
  ~ID,    ~DAYS,  ~FREQUENCY,
  "ads",   20,      3,
  "jwa",   45,      2,
  "mno",   4,       1,
  "ads",   13,      3,
  "jwa",   60,      2,
  "ads",   18,      3
)

# Subtract each number in a numeric vector with the one following it
rolling_subtraction <- function(x) {
  out <- vector('numeric', length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(out)) {
    out[[i]] <- x[i] - x[i + 1] # x[i + 1] is NA if the index is out of bounds
  }

  out
}

# Arrange data.frame in order of ID / Days and apply rolling subtraction
df %>% 
  arrange(ID, desc(DAYS)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(days_diff = rolling_subtraction(DAYS))
```